# Opera multiple file upload sends files to $_POST instead of $_FILES - suggestions?

Tags: php, html, file, input, opera

I tried googling this with little success. Can I make Opera upload files to $_FILES or will I have to start editing the PHP script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't multiple file upload working in Opera?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887511/why-isnt-multiple-file-upload-working-in-opera)

Comment: Sorry, can I see the page you're having problems with? I've written and maintained many forms with file upload and PHP backend, I've never seen such problems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is better explained here:
[How do I make Opera upload files like other browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897149/how-do-i-make-opera-upload-files-like-other-browsers)

Comment: Yes, that's my repost as I got no replies. It seems I'm the only one who's ever bumped into this problem :3

Answer (score 1):

have your form the attribute "enctype" set to "multipart/form-data"  ?

Comment: As I said the problem is only with Opera, I thought it was obvious this works in other browsers. Thus, yes, enctype is set to multipart/form-data. Sorry for my lack of information